# Failure getting entry for 0x7f050000 (t=4 e=0) in package 0 (error -75) name=com.android.keyguard

Tags: android

I am trying to get the list of all applications installed in my device. I wrote the following code for the purpose:

```
  public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
        return apps;
    }
```

I am using `Collections.sort` to sort my application. Now, while running the above code, I am getting issue like:

> Failure getting entry for 0x7f050000 (t=4 e=0) in package 0 (error -75) name=com.android.keyguard

```
Failure retrieving text 0x7f050000 in package com.android.keyguard
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050000
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:255)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1052)
at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:120)
at com.example.khan.spycameralocker.SettingsFragment.getAllApp(SettingsFragment.java:53)
at com.example.khan.spycameralocker.SettingsFragment.onCreateView(SettingsFragment.java:35)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16670)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2058)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1374)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5905)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:791)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop
```

My app doesn't crashes, but takes time in launch. Please help me to solve this.

Edit :
Other methods in the fragment is:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        getAllApp();

        lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.applist);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),appNames,packageNames,appIcons));

        return view;
    }


    private void getAllApp() {
        final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
//        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications =
//                packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications =
                getInstalledApplication(getActivity());

        for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : installedApplications)
        {
            appNames.add(String.valueOf(appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)));
            packageNames.add(appInfo.packageName);
            appIcons.add(getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(appInfo));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show `onCreateView ` method code also

Comment: Have a look on my edits.

Comment: I think `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050000` is the main culprit here. There are a lot of question on this on stackoverflow. Looks like I don't have icon for some application.

Comment: Log `appInfo.packageName` and check for which application getting this issue

Comment: I get this issue, before any logging. Means I got the error, before any logging takes place.

Comment: Add logging before `appNames.add(String.valueOf(appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)));` line

Comment: I did the same `Log.d(TAG,"I am getting: " + appInfo.packageName);

    appNames.add(String.valueOf(appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113321/discussion-between-learner-and--k).